# Is it possible in mysql to display the sum of two count() results obtained from two different "group by" criteria on the same table?

Tags: mysql

I have the data table as follows
 [GameTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6irn.jpg)

And this is the result i need
[ResultTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI9oe.jpg)

I tried this but iit wouldn't work
(
(select count(*) from game group by team_1)
+
(select count(*) from game group by team_2)
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use union all:

```
select Team_id, sum(Game_count) as 'Game_count'
from (
  select Team_1 as 'Team_id', count(*) as 'Game_count'
  from games
  group by Team_1
  union all 
  select Team_2, count(*)
  from games
  group by Team_2
) as q
```

group by Team_id